# Reference a cell from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets 'Sheet A' and 'Sheet B' (note the space in the sheet name) in my excel workbook. The requirement is that I need to use values from cells in 'Sheet A', in 'Sheet B'.

The macro code I wrote for this is something like this:

```
Sub Ratios()

B4 = 'Sheet A'!A25 / 'Sheet A'!A11

End Sub
```

Excel said that there was a syntax error. So I tried something like:

```
Sub Ratios()

[B4] = ['Sheet A'!A25] / ['Sheet A'!A11]

End Sub
```

...but to no avail. The error this time was that there was a type mismatch. The values in the cell A25 and A11 are integers.

Any idea on what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @pnuts. There are many ways to write what you want.

Comment: @pnuts: Will try this approach going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for pointing to a cell on another sheet is way off. Instead:

`B4 = Sheets("Sheet A").Range("A25")/Sheets("Sheet A").Range("A11")`

You can also used `Cells()` to point to cells by Row and Column number, which is helpful at times:

`B4 = Sheets("Sheet A").cells(25, 1)/Sheets("Sheet A").cells(11, 1)`

Edited to add: This will store the value of that division in Variable B4. If you wanting to write the result of the division to cell `B4` in `"Sheet B"` then:

`Sheets("Sheet B").Range("B4").value = Sheets("Sheet A").Range("A25")/Sheets("Sheet A").Range("A11")`

But at that point, why use VBA? Just use a formula and save yourself an unnecessary headache.

Comment: It's tough to catch the things we take for granted, like variables.

Comment: + 1 It is perfect now :) Made a small edit. Hope you don't mind?

Comment: Always appreciated when I miss something painfully obvious. Whatever helps OP find their way.